# Styling ReactJs Component Options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-css-modules

I am doing some research for a large project which will use reactJs and all html elements will be converted to React Components.

As we all know, css has a big problem with globals so there is a lot of posibility of css conflicts.

There are lots of different options for this including:

- Atomic Design
- SMACSS
- OOCSS

or using libraries like:

- Radium
- React Style
- React Inline
- jsxstyle
- React JSS
- React Inline CSS
- React Look
- React Statics Styles

All of these have something good but at the same time all are under experiment and missing things.

In other words none of them solve all the css problems in react component styling or some just try to solve a problem that isn't there.

After trying all of them I am half way thinking that I should just link to common styles css files and have a css file specific to each component and target that css file from within the component.

Has anyone here had experience in styling react components in large project and have any feedback on it or suggestions?

I simply cannot make up my mind on just using straight css or javascript for this.

Is there anything I've missed to research?

Comment: i like to use radium with plain old bootstrap. let the css framework take care of the layout for you, but being able to truly compose styles with OOP *without* a separate css build is awesome. works great with `PropTypes`, i.e., a button component *should have* some error color associated with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong on including CSS with your solution, SASS and LESS are awesome.

However, I personally like inline styles a as a plain JS object because it gives you the whole power of JS, so you can be as dynamic as you want, make the calculations all the calcs you need without pre-processing css, etc...

The React team has been investing in this for a while (React Native already uses this by default) here's a to [React Native Styles](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html), and a [Presentation from a Facebook engineer](http://blog.vjeux.com/2014/javascript/react-css-in-js-nationjs.html), and a [Proposal from the reactjs/react-future repo](https://github.com/reactjs/react-future/blob/master/04%20-%20Layout/04%20-%20Inline%20Styles.md), and there are nice libraries like Radium which helps you a lot.

CSS in JS is surely getting better each day, so yeah, I'd advise on making that jump. :)

Comment: Yeah I've seen those presentations and of course you need to add yet another library (Radium) in order to do :hover etc ... Radium only sorts out part of the problem...not convinced with it yet

Comment: Yeah, is a matter of preference right now (unless you do React Native). I'd advise on trying it out more in depth, if you still aren't convinced, then there's nothing wrong on continuing to use CSS. :)